# How to enforce size of a ClickPane inside a Column

Tags: dynamic, size, column

I would like to use an image as a **ClickPane**, inside a column. I want the image to appear at its native size.

Outside of the column, this works:

```
size = 256;
image = ConstantImage[.5, {size, size}];
DynamicModule[{},
 ClickPane[image, (Print[#]) &]
 ]
```

But when I put the **ClickPane** inside a Column, it always displays as a small size, regardless of the value of **size**.

```
size = 256;
image = ConstantImage[.5, {size, size}];
DynamicModule[{},
 Column[{ClickPane[image,
    (pt = #) &], Dynamic@pt}, ItemSize -> Full]
 ]
```

I have tried different values for **ItemSize** but nothing seems to have an effect.

How can I force the image to appear at its native size?

Comment: Add an explicit `ImageSize` to `ConstantImage` or wrap it in `Image[image, ImageSize->{size, size}]` By default that is set to `Automatic` to allow for this kind of context-based resizing

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are looking for : `Style[..., ImageSizeMultipliers -> {1, 1}]`

```
size = 256;
image = ConstantImage[.5, {size, size}];
DynamicModule[{},
 Style[#, ImageSizeMultipliers -> {1, 1}] & @
   Column[{ClickPane[image, (pt = #) &], Dynamic@pt}, 
   ItemSize -> Full]]
```

[image]

Compare with :

```
size = 256;
image = ConstantImage[.5, {size, size}];
DynamicModule[{}, ClickPane[image, (Print[#]) &]]
```

[image]